Passing Context ForEach variables to It blocks
Why are the variables in my Context -ForEach cases not being passed to the It blocks underneath the Context? I have this code in my test file.
BeforeAll {
    Import-Module Pester
    Import-Module MyModule
}

Describe 'MyFunction' {
    BeforeAll {
        Mock -ModuleName MyModule Invoke-RestMethod { return @{ access_token = 'mocked access token' } }
    }

    Context 'When the service is <service>' -ForEach @(
        @{Service = 'MicrosoftGraph'}
        @{Service = 'SharePointOnline'}
    ) {
        It 'Should return an access token' {
            InModuleScope MyModule {
                Mock New-GraphJwtAssertion {}
                $TenantId = '<tenantId>'
                $ClientId = '<clientId>'
                $Certificate = <certificate>
                $result = MyFunction -TenantId $TenantId -ClientId $ClientId -Certificate $Certificate -Service $Service

                $result | Should -Be 'mocked access token'
            }
        }
    }
}

I suspect the issue might have to do with the InModuleScope block which I'm using because the New-GraphJwtAssertion function is a private function of the module.
The Service parameter on MyFunction uses a ValidateSet attribute and when I run the tests I just get an error that "The argument "" does not belong to the set <set values>".
So the Service variable from the ForEach hashtable doesn't appear to be passed to the It block.
What do I need to change in this test to be able to pass those variables through to the It blocks so they can be used.

The documentation at https://pester.dev/docs/commands/InModuleScope#example-2 has some example of passing values into InModuleScope. See this quote in particular - “No variables from the outside are available inside the scriptblock without explicitly passing them in using -Parameters or -ArgumentList”.

@mclayton Thanks for the link, for some reason I got fixated on the Modules usage page and never looked at the actual InModuleScope help page. Thanks for pointing that out, it got me over the issue.
